# ExecuteStoreQuery throws System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

Sorry but I just cannot explain the error I am getting even after reading a lot of close-to-problem blogs.

I have the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddUserToRole 
    @UserName nvarchar(256), @RoleId nvarchar(128),
    @UserId nvarchar(128) OUTPUT  
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT @UserId = Id FROM dbo.AspNetUsers WHERE dbo.AspNetUsers.UserName = @UserName
  INSERT INTO dbo.AspNetUserRoles (UserId,RoleId) VALUES(@UserId,@RoleId)
END
GO
```

I am calling it as follows:

```
var userNameParameter = new SqlParameter("UserName", userName);
var roleIdParameter = new SqlParameter("RoleId", roleId);
string userId = "";
var UserIdParameter = new SqlParameter("UserId", userId);
UserIdParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("AddUserToRole @UserName, @RoleId, @UserId", userNameParameter, roleIdParameter, UserIdParameter);
```

but I get the following exception
    The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Sorry again but I will appreciate any help. I don't want just the fix but I want to understand what the exact problem is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Exec AddUserToRole  @UserName, @RoleId, @UserId", userNameParameter, roleIdParameter, UserIdParameter);
```

Comment: Thanks Mahdi but it is giving me same error. I am using EF6, if that matters.

Comment: try return a string value in your sp.
after insert commend, write Select "foo"